# How to dynamically load xunit tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium, ienumerable, xunit

I have a set of tests that are loaded dynamically using the  `ClassData` decorator:

```
using Xunit;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace reviewWebApp.UITests
{
    public class ticketFieldWebAppShould
    {
        [Trait("Category", "Smoke")]
        [Xunit.Theory]
        [ClassData(typeof(repositories.readForms))]
        public void LoadForms(string formNo , List<string> elemList)
        {
             
            using(IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost:61851/");
                DemoHelper.Pause();
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SendKeys(formNo);
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
                Actions action = new Actions(driver);
                DemoHelper.Pause();
                action.KeyDown(Keys.Control);
                action.KeyDown(Keys.Alt);
                action.Build().Perform();
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert().SendKeys(elemList[0]);
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
                driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The class that has the data is in a separate file:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;

namespace reviewWebApp.UITests.repositories
{
    public class readForms : IEnumerable<object[]>
    {
        public IEnumerator<object[]> GetEnumerator()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 3; i++)
            {
                yield return new object[] { "t"+ i, new List<string> { "f", "" } };
            }
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Since the for loop goes twice I would expect the number of tests to be 2 distinct tests in the test explorer.
However, in the test explorer, I see 1 test that will open chrome twice.
[image]

The problem is that if a test fails I would not know where or which, since there is only a single test. Is it possible to decompose the code in two distinct tests dynamically loaded?